# How do I map from Shift-Tab to Control-I in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to do the opposite of <kbd>Tab</kbd> so that I can move forward and backward in the jump list.

I cannot just map `<Shift>^I` to `^O`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct mapping is:

`:nnoremap <S-Tab> <c-o>`